# How to call bash functions

Tags: bash

Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way..  But here I what I am trying to do.  Do most of my work with Java but just switched to a unix (bash) environment.  I am doing this:

```
[~/Desktop/bashPlay]% cat myFunc
#!/bin/bash

ls2(){
        echo "Hello World"
}

ls3(){
        echo "Testing"
}

echo "this is a test"   
ls2 # this calls a function

[~/Desktop/bashPlay]% myFunc
this is a test
Hello World
```

But I have two functions in my file and I want to be able to call them separately from the command line.  Ie: `myFunc.ls2()` or even just `ls2`.  I know that I can add the functions to my `.bashrc` file but is there any other way that I can execute these functions without adding them to my `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One way to do this, that involves a bit more typing, is via the `source` command. To call a function from myFunc you could use `source myFunc; ls2` and it would output Hello World.

So for example, I have a file called `say.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function talk()
{
        echo "hi!"
}
```

now I want to call it's `talk()` function from the command line:

```
[john@awesome ~]$ source say.sh; talk
hi!
```

to call it from another bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source say.sh
talk
```

You can also put each in a separate script and add them in a directory which is in your PATH variable.

so for example, in one script called `hello` you'd have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

now put it in one of the directories in your PATH, which you can view by running `echo $PATH`. You can add another directory to your PATH if you'd like or use an existing one. Once you've copied the file there, make it executable with `chmod +x filename`.

Comment: Just to be clear: you only have to source the file once per script or shell startup. You can call the function as many times as you want after that without referencing the sourced file again.

Comment: can you show how to do it with arguments?

Answer (score 15):

If you are like me, you dont want to clutter your environment with functions.  You also have a group of functions that belong together in terms of what they do, so putting them in the same script file makes sense.  (I know that a folder with multiple files could serve the same purpose).  Here is a possible solution that allows you to call a specific function in the script:

```
$ cat functions.sh    
#!/bin/bash

ls2() {
        echo "Hello World"
}

ls3() {
        echo "Testing $*"
}

# the next line calls the function passed as the first parameter to the script.
# the remaining script arguments can be passed to this function.

$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 

$ ./functions.sh ls2    
Hello World   
$ ./functions.sh ls3    
Testing     
$ ./functions.sh ls3 first_arg    
Testing first_arg    
$
```

Comment: I like this a lot more than `source` since it can handle having two functions of the same name in two different sh files. I refined it to handle an arbitrary number of parameters by replacing `$1 $2 $3 $4 $5` with
`FUNC_CALL=$1; shift; $FUNC_CALL "$@"`

Comment: @ChuckWilbur: Why jump through hoops?  Just change the last line to `"$@"`. P.S. Your approach is actually wrong; the last part should be ``"$FUNC_CALL" "$@"``  (i.e., ``$FUNC_CALL`` should be in quotes).

Comment: What is `"$FUNC_CALL"`?

Answer (score 7):

Another approach would be to create a script called `functions.sh` ( in the `~/bin` directory for example) .

In this script, you add all your personal function definitions (let's say every time you add a function you add it to this file...)

Finally you just have to add the `source ~/bin/functions.sh` line to your `.bashrc` file. This way you will be able to call them from the command line, your `.bashrc` will stay clean, and you will have a specific place for your personal functions.

Answer (score 1):

The dot operator or `source` builtin in `bash` is analogous to the `import` statement in Java.

You can read more about the [dot operator](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html) or the [`source` builtin](http://learnlinux.tsf.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch10s02.html).

Comment: Sometimes, If you are inside a script, and want to call a function, it can be handy to `printf "$(functionName)"